# cannot call subroutine in batch file when launched from Task Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, scheduled-tasks

I have written a simple batch file script that is used to back up test data daily, weekly and monthly.

The script works well if i run the batch file directly, however I have encountered a problem when launching from Windows Task Scheduler (Windows 10).

I have a log file that the batch file writes to, so I know that the script executes. However the problem appears to be when using if statements and calling subroutines.

the main piece of code looks like this:

```
:: call daily backup every day    
call :dailybackup

:: call weekly backup if today is sunday
if %day%==Sun ( call :weeklybackup )

:: call monthly backup if today is the 28th
if %dd%==28 ( call :monthlybackup )

call :log "FINISHED"

:: main program complete - exit batch file
exit /b
```

The each sub routine writes log messages to the log file. I have verified that the :weeklybackup and :monthly backup routines are called correctly when I run the batch file manually, however not when run from Task Scheduler. The :dailybackup routine executes always.

Just one point to clarify, I know that the batch file exits cleanly as I receive the "FINISHED" log message.

Any thoughts are greatly received

ps I have just been asked how %day% and %dd% are calculated.....

```
:: Get the current day of the month
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ("%date%") do (
    set dd=%%a
    set mm=%%b
    set yy=%%c
)

:: determine the day of the week
for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek' ) do (
    if %%a==1 set day=Mon
    if %%a==2 set day=Tue
    if %%a==3 set day=Wed
    if %%a==4 set day=Thu
    if %%a==5 set day=Fri
    if %%a==6 set day=Sat
    if %%a==7 set day=Sun
)
```

Comment: How do you retrieve the values `%day%` and `%dd%`?

Comment: Add lines `call :log "day=%day%"` and `call :log "dd=%dd%"` before the `if` test for each. Run manually and as a scheduled task and see whether there's any difference.

Comment: thanks for the comment. The %day% and %d% variables seem to be calculated correctly. I have updated the original post to show how there are determined

Comment: So - was there any difference in the values reported in the log file between started-manually and started-by scheduler?

Comment: no - both report day=Tue and dd=13

Comment: Well - that's a real mystery. I'd be inserting `call :log "message"` lines in the subroutines `:weekly/monthlybackup` to see whether the routines are entered but fail for some reason.

Comment: i have done that - :weeklyBackup and :monthlyBackup are not called when run from Task Scheduler, they are if I run from cmd line or by opening the batch file. I might have to implement as three separate batch files and schedule them as separate tasks